# Conditionally show a Picker(section) using Vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

i am trying to achieve the following: I have a modal inside and inside i have a date picker and a time picker. i Only want to show one at at a time. So when i click on the button inside the date picker, the time picker should show up and vice versa.

I have set the v-if on the time picker but it's not working the way as expected. 
Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVmZRK?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
   <v-app id="inspire">
   <span class="title mb-3">  {{ computedDateFormattedMomentjs }} {{ time1 
}} </span>
   <v-layout>
    <v-btn @click.stop = "modal1 = true">
      <v-icon> calendar_today </v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    <v-dialog
     v-model="modal1"
     transition="scale-transition"
     width="300px">      
     <v-date-picker v-model="date">
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn @click.stop="toggleTimePicker">
          <v-icon>access_time</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
       </v-date-picker>
      <v-time-picker v-model="time1" v-if="modal1 != true">
         <v-spacer></v-spacer>
         <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal1 = false" >Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal1 = false"  >OK</v-btn>
    </v-time-picker>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-layout>
   </v-app>
 </div>

 <script>
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
   date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
   time1: null,
   modal2: false,
   modal1: false
  }),

  computed: {
   computedDateFormattedMomentjs () {
  return this.date ? moment(this.date).format('MMMM Do, YYYY') : ''
  },
  computedDateFormattedDatefns () {
  return this.date ? format(this.date, 'MMMM Do, YYYY') : ''
   }
 },
 methods: {
   toggleTimePicker() {
    this.modal1 = false
  }
 }
})
 </script>
```

Thank you in advance all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `modal1` to bind your dialog and your `v-time-picker`. When `modal1` is true, your dialog and datepicker are shown. When you togggle you make `modal1` false which hides both!.

the first thing to do is to use the other data property `modal2` or something similar, and then use a `v-if` and `v-else` to toggle between the datepicker and the time picker:

**Note the `v-if` and `v-else`**

```
<v-date-picker v-model="date" v-if="!modal2">
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn @click.stop="toggleTimePicker">
        <v-icon>access_time</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
</v-date-picker>
<v-time-picker v-model="time1" v-else>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal1 = false" >Cancel</v-btn>
    <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal1 = false"  >OK</v-btn>
</v-time-picker>
```

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    time1: null,
    modal2: false,
    modal1: false
  }),

  computed: {
    computedDateFormattedMomentjs () {
      return this.date ? moment(this.date).format('MMMM Do, YYYY') : ''
    },
    computedDateFormattedDatefns () {
      return this.date ? format(this.date, 'MMMM Do, YYYY') : ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTimePicker() {
      this.modal2 = !this.modal2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.18/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <span class="title mb-3">  {{ computedDateFormattedMomentjs }} {{ time1 }} </span>
    <v-layout>
        <v-btn @click.stop = "modal1 = true">
          <v-icon> calendar_today </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        <v-dialog
         v-model="modal1"
         transition="scale-transition"
         width="300px">      
         <v-date-picker v-model="date" v-if="!modal2">
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn @click.stop="toggleTimePicker">
              <v-icon>access_time</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          </v-date-picker>
          <v-time-picker v-model="time1" v-else>
             <v-spacer></v-spacer>
             <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal1 = false" >Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal1 = false"  >OK</v-btn>
        </v-time-picker>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This is more of a follow up question, do you know how i can make it happen so that everytime i close it, the datepicker shows up first. Right now if i click outside or close it, the last picker to show up appears on reopening.

Comment: Sure, you can call a method `onClose` to set `modal2 = false` before setting `modal1 = false`, or use a `watcher` to set `modal2 = false` when `modal1` is set to `false`

Comment: I just noticed it, how do i make the date picker for when i click outside on the window. right now i have to click on the icon itself to set modal2 = false

Comment: You need to check if vuetify provides events that you can use when the modal closes.